# The completion of the closure

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a subspace $X$ of a metric space $M$. I'm wondering if the completion of $X$ is isometric to the completion of the closure of $X$.

I believe so, due to the uniqueness of the completion, it doesn't seem to me that the completions would behave differently. But I couldn't construct the isometry.

But I saw in my book an exercise asked to prove that there is a subspace of the completion of $X$ that is isometric to the closure of $X$ in $M$.

Can both statements be true? And any hint for the proof?

Comment: Example: let $M=(-1,1)$ and $X=(0,1)$.

Comment: @Berci Example of what? The completion of $X$ "is" $[0,1]$ and the completion of the closure of $X$ is also $[0,1]$....

Comment: Yes, correct. But the closure of $X$ is a proper subset of it.

Comment: You mean the closure of $X$ in $M$ or in the completion of $M$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the closure of $X$ in $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are true.

Hint for the second one: if $y$ is in the closure of $X$ then there's a convergent - hence Cauchy - sequence of points $x_n\in X$ that converges to $y$.

Comment: That's what I did, for the second part, but my problem was in the formalization of the isometry, my difficulty was in defining the subspace that is isometric to the closure.

Comment: Assign the equivalence class of $(x_n)$ to $y$. That's going to be the isometric embedding.